# Is it possible to make Spring ignore a bean property that is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to have Spring not throw exception in below case?

```
<bean id="myMain" class="pak.Main">
  <property name="name" value="myName"/>
  <property name="age" value="100"/>
  <property name="human" value="true"/>
</bean>


public class Main {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml")
        .getBean("myMain", Main.class);
  }
}
```

This is thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myMain' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'human' of bean class [pak.Main]: Bean property 'human' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Comment: You can't simply remove the property from the bean definition?

Comment: Then I wouldn't have a question, would I? :)

Comment: What's the specific use case? There might be many options but, as others noted, if the type is fully known, you shouldn't have to do any "magic" to ignore properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine my surprise that the answer is yes.

Enter [InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor.html)... or more specifically (and easier to implement) [InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter.html).

This bean post processor is invoked before instantiation of the properties on a bean. The method you can override to achieve what you are trying to do is [postProcessPropertyValues](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter.html#postProcessPropertyValues%28org.springframework.beans.PropertyValues,%20java.beans.PropertyDescriptor%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

This method is given the information about it's bean and it's properties. You can then modify the bean's properties in any way you see fit. Specifically there is a [PropertyValue.setOptional(boolean)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyValue.html#setOptional%28boolean%29) method that looks like it would interest you.

Throwing together a quick example using your scenario, define a class as such:

MyInstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor.java:

```
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyValue;
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyValues;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyInstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor extends InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter {

    @Override
    public PropertyValues postProcessPropertyValues(PropertyValues pvs, PropertyDescriptor[] pds, Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof pak.Main) {
            for (PropertyValue pv : pvs.getPropertyValues()) {
                if ("human".equals(pv.getName())) {
                    pv.setOptional(true);
                }
            }
        }
        return pvs;
    }

}
```

Then make sure the following line is in your context somewhere:

```
<bean id="instantiationAwarePP" class="pak.MyInstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

And you are golden.

P.S. You might also need to define `<context:annotation-config />` in your context so that post-processors are automatically registered... but I can't recall if that's necessary.

Comment: Great, thanks! <context:annotation-config /> was not necessary. One thing to notice is that I couldn't just extend my Main class, which is ok for some of the other post processors. For this one I had to make a new class as you're doing in your answer.